# Extending WC_Product class in a custom plugin error issue (WC_Product class not found)

Tags: php, wordpress, class, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm trying to extend the WC_Product class to add "property1" and "property2" to the protected array $data but when I try to run my plugin it give me the next error:

> WC_Product not found.

Here is my code:

```
class WC_MyClass extends WC_Product {
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        array_push($data, "property1", "property2");
    }
}
```

What I need is to extend WC_Product class in my plugin.

Plugin details:
My plugin consist in calculate shipping costs according FedEx table rate for my country.
To do this I'm using the Woocommerce Table Rate Shipping plugin. The problem is that FedEx sometimes takes into acount not the real weight but volumetric so I want to do a plugin to determinate which weight is greater and assign it to a variable. The idea is to set a shipping weight to use it to calculate shipping cost and not to modify the product weight specification. This is why I'm trying to extend the WC_Product class to add to it the shipping weight property. I have already done all calculus, now I just need to store the shipping weight to use it with the Woocommerce Table Rate Shipping plugin.

Documentation: [WC_Product class - $data property](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Product.html#42-96)

Comment: maybe `include_once( WC_ABSPATH . 'includes/abstracts/abstract-wc-product.php' );` before the class definition? How to you use your WC_MyClass?

Comment: Are you hooking this to run after WooCommerce? `add_action( 'init', 'my_wrapper_function' );` Eg, like in this article: http://jeroensormani.com/adding-a-custom-woocommerce-product-type/

Comment: @pants I think I found the problem, I had `add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'myFunction', 10);` but I had wrote the class part out of `myFunction()`

Comment: @jeger it gaves me an error `Warning: include_once(WC_ABSPATH/includes/abstracts/abstract-wc-product.php): failed to open stream`

Comment: You may need to read before this WooCommerce related documentation: 
[Creating a plugin for WooCommerce](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/create-a-plugin/) and [Implementing the WC Integration Class](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/implementing-wc-integration/) … You should (may be) explain what you are trying to do in WooCommerce (updating your question), to get a more accurate help.

Comment: Instead of `init` I like to use `woocommerce_loaded`

Comment: @LoicTheAztec thank you very much, I think this is going to help me to structure my plugin.

Comment: @ElisabetGonzález Welcome. You can always ask here if you need some further help… This documentation should help you to go much more further in your coding process.

Answer (score 6):

If you have the extend function on its own, WooCommerce classes will not yet be created. You have to add the class extension to the `init` hook or `woocommerce_init` like this:

```
add_action( 'init', 'register_myclass' );
function register_myclass() {
  class WC_MyClass extends WC_Product {
    /*now you can override whatever you like*/
  }
}
```

Comment: please check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61551333/using-woocommerce-classes-from-a-custom-plugin-that-uses-composer-autoload Not sure if it's the same issue though

Answer (score 1):

you have to tell php that you want to do that on a class variable

```
class WC_MyClass extends WC_Product {
  function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->data[] = "property1";
    $this->data[] = "property2";
  }
}
```

Comment: this don't fix my issue, the problem is that the WC_Product class is not found. I think the problem is related to directories but I don't want to modify Woocommerce files, I want to use my own plugin to modify some things of Woocommerce so I don't know how to get acces to WC_Product class.

Comment: have you added and enabled your plugin in wordpress?

Comment: yes, actually I had not had any problems with my plugin before because I was not extending a class. I had coded just the logical part of my plugin but now I want to storage a value directly in a Woocommerce class but I need to add a new item in a protected array to do this so I want to exten that class.

Comment: @ElisabetGonzález, did you by any chance get a working solution for this? I am currently facing the same situation. I need to extend the WC_Product class in order to add some elements to the protected $data array and also to add some new functions, but I cannot make it work. Can you please help?