# How to use woocommerce classes from a custom plugin that uses composer autoload

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, composer-php, autoload

Im using Composer autoload in my plugin to make it easier to manage all the files and classes instead of writing everysingle time `require_once`

However Im having trouble trying to access native woocommerce classes. My classes are defined with namespaces as for example:

```
<?php
namespace Inc\Api;

class RestClientApi
{
....
}
```

If I try to call a woocommerce class within this class for example:

```
<?php
namespace Inc\Api;

class RestClientApi
{

  public $example = new WC_product();

}
```

I get the error `Class Inc/Api/WC_product not found` I know what the error means, but I don't have idea how to use Woocommerce classes from my custom plugin, considering I'm using autoload and namespaces in my custom plugin classes.

**UPDATE**
As requested I added my autoload configuration, it is pretty simple, Im just calling my /inc folder

```
"autoload": {
        "psr-4": {"Inc\\": "./inc"}
    }
```

Comment: Can you share more details? How does your autoloader configuration look like? Where are your classes stored - are these filepaths consistent with your autoloader configuration?

Comment: @NicoHaase I added the autoload configuration as well.

Answer (score 0):

In your plugin composer.json, add something like this (you adapt it to your needs):

```
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "WooCommerceNamespace\\":"path/to/woocomerce/classes/folder"
        }
    },
```

Then run a

```sh
composer dump-autoload
```

inside the composer.json folder.

Then add to your plugin file: use WooCommerceNamespace\WC and the WC class should now be available.

(if your WC.php file already has a namespace declaration, use that namespace in your psr-4 declaration).